# Is String.substringWithRange in bounds?

Tags: swift, string, cocoa

I'm having a problem with non-latin character sets, and I need to check that a Range is in bounds before performing .substringWithRange. This seems really easy, but I can't find the way to do this.

Given a range:

```
let lastCharRange = currentString.endIndex.predecessor() ..< currentString.endIndex
```

How can I check:

```
let lastExpected                = expectedString.substringWithRange(lastCharRange)
```

is in bounds?

Comment: Your snippets indicate that you're trying to use the index from one String on another. Is that correct? That's not legal; indexes are only valid for the String that generated them.

Comment: Yes that's correct, and probably why I'm having this problem. Give me a moment and I'll update my question to express what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Actually - what I'm trying to do is easy, the correct answer to this question should be that it's not legal. @JoshCaswell do you want to put that as an answer?

Comment: Tried to make a general answer out of the situation. Let me know if you need more/something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes are tied closely to the `String` that generated them -- actually to the `String`'s `CharacterView`, which is a `CollectionType`. This holds true generally for collections.

So, you simply can't use the `Index` you got from one `String` on another `String`.

Depending on what you are doing, you might have to get a substring from the first and then search the second. You can also get the two `String`s' `CharacterView`s and work with them via their collection-based interface: `expectedString.characters.last`, for example.